# pandas groupby fillna code does not work and gives error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean, fillna

I have the dataframe like this:

```
data = {'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
        'job': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer','teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer'],
        'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
        'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
        'date': ['6-12-2022', '6-12-2022', '6-12-2022','6-13-2022', '6-13-2022', '6-13-2022']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data) df
```

I add data for another date as null values:

```
    |name   |job        |age|weight |date
|---|-------|-----------|---|-------|--------
|0  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |160    |6-12-2022
|1  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |209    |6-12-2022
|2  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |130    |6-12-2022
|3  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |164    |6-13-2022
|4  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |206    |6-13-2022
|5  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |132    |6-13-2022
|6  |Alex   |teacher    |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|7  |Ben    |doctor     |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|8  |Marry  |engineer   |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
```

Now, I want to fillna values in weight column after groupby name and job, and get average

I tried these lines of codes:

```
df.loc[df.weight.isnull(), 'weight'] = df.groupby(["name", "job"]).weight.transform('mean')
```

or

```
df['weight'] = df['weight'].fillna(df.groupby(["name", "job"])['weight'].mean())
```

or

```
df['weight'] = df.groupby(["name", "job"], sort=False)['weight'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

For the first one, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
```

name and job are string, and weight is flout64.

and for the rest it runs but doesnt fill na values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose using Andrej Kesely answer might be enough, but have in mind that using apply with pandas is not good performance-wise.

A better option to maintain performance is to use `.transform('mean')` like

```py
  df["age"].fillna(df.groupby(["name", "job"])["age"].transform("mean"), inplace=True) 
  df["weight"].fillna(df.groupby(["name", "job"])["weight"].transform("mean"), inplace=True)
```

This is just a comparison between the groupby and apply strategy and the transform one. Where slow referes to the groupby-apply and fast to the transform.

[image]

To reproduce this comparison you can run this

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

def build_dataset(N):
  names = ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry']
  jobs = ['teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer','teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer']

  data = {
      'name':  np.random.choice(names, size=N),
      'job': np.random.choice(jobs, size=N),
      'age': np.random.uniform(low=10, high=90, size=N),
      'weight': np.random.uniform(low=60, high=150, size=N)
  }

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.1).index, "age"] = np.nan
  df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.1).index, "weight"] = np.nan
  return df

def slow_way(df):
  df = df.copy()
  def fn(x):
      x["age"].fillna(x["age"].mean(), inplace=True)
      x["weight"].fillna(x["weight"].mean(), inplace=True)
      return x


  return df.groupby(["name", "job"]).apply(fn)

def fast_way(df):
  df = df.copy()
  df["age"].fillna(df.groupby(["name", "job"])["age"].transform("mean"), inplace=True) 
  df["weight"].fillna(df.groupby(["name", "job"])["weight"].transform("mean"), inplace=True) 

  return df

Ns = np.arange(10, 100000, step=1000, dtype=np.int32)
slow = []
fast = []
size = []
for N in tqdm(Ns):
  for i in range(10):
    df = build_dataset(N)
    start = time.time()
    _ = slow_way(df)
    end = time.time()
    slow.append(end-start)
    start = time.time()
    _ = fast_way(df)
    end = time.time()
    fast.append(end-start)
    size.append(N)

df = pd.DataFrame({"N": size, "slow": slow, "fast": fast})
df_group = df.groupby("N").mean()
df_group.plot(figsize=(30,10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    x["age"].fillna(x["age"].mean(), inplace=True)
    x["weight"].fillna(x["weight"].mean(), inplace=True)
    return x


df = df.groupby(["name", "job"]).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name       job   age  weight       date
0   Alex   teacher  27.0   160.0  6-12-2022
1    Ben    doctor  32.0   209.0  6-12-2022
2  Marry  engineer  78.0   130.0  6-12-2022
3   Alex   teacher  27.0   164.0  6-13-2022
4    Ben    doctor  32.0   206.0  6-13-2022
5  Marry  engineer  78.0   132.0  6-13-2022
6   Alex   teacher  27.0   162.0  6-14-2022
7    Ben    doctor  32.0   207.5  6-14-2022
8  Marry  engineer  78.0   131.0  6-14-2022
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `mean` with non numeric values, you must convert:

```
df.loc[df.weight.isnull(), 'weight'] = pd.to_numeric(df['weight']).groupby([df["name"], df["job"]]).transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
    name       job   age weight       date
0   Alex   teacher    27    160  6-12-2022
1    Ben    doctor    32    209  6-12-2022
2  Marry  engineer    78    130  6-12-2022
3   Alex   teacher    27    164  6-13-2022
4    Ben    doctor    32    206  6-13-2022
5  Marry  engineer    78    132  6-13-2022
6   Alex   teacher   NaN  162.0  6-14-2022
7    Ben    doctor   NaN  207.5  6-14-2022
8  Marry  engineer   NaN  131.0  6-1242022
```